# Laravel get a query to check if at least one of two relationships exist with QueryBuilder without ignoring other filters

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a model Affiliate that has a relationship hasMany() with Activities and Transfers

Im filtering my affiliates now and want to retrieve the affiliates that have at leat 1 activity OR at least one transfer (it can have 0 activities and 1 transfer and will pass). Also I must ignore a given array of invalid affiliate's ids

this is what I tried

```php
$affiliates = Affiliate::whereNotIn('id',$invalidIds);
        if ($params['sales']){
            $affiliates = $affiliates->whereHas('activities', static function (Builder $builder) use ($params) {
                $builder->where('status','>',0)
                        ->where('status','<',8)
                        ;  
            })->orWhereHas('transfers', static function (Builder $builder) use ($params) {
                $builder->where('status','>',0)
                        ->where('status','<',8)  
                        ;
            });
        }
        $affiliates = $affiliates->get();
```

using the whereHas and orWhereHas should work but the problem I believe is that in the orWhereHas() it currently ignores the other filters (in this case the filter that ignores the $invalidIds for affiliates) so I get the affiliates that at least have one activity or one transfer but I don't ignore the invalid ids

am I doing something wrong? or there is a different way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$affiliates = Affiliate::whereNotIn('id',$invalidIds);

if ($params['sales']){
  $affiliates = $affiliates->where(function($query){
    $query->whereHas('activities', function ($q1){
        $q1->where('status','>',0)->where('status','<',8);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('transfers',function ($q2){
        $q1->where('status','>',0)->where('status','<',8);
    });
  });
}
$affiliates = $affiliates->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I think playing around with method order will work.

```
        $affiliates = Affiliate::query();
    if ($params['sales']) {
        $affiliates = $affiliates->whereHas('activities', static function (Builder $builder) use ($params) {
            $builder->where('status', '>', 0)
                ->where('status', '<', 8);
        })->orWhereHas('transfers', static function (Builder $builder) use ($params) {
            $builder->where('status', '>', 0)
                ->where('status', '<', 8);
        });
    }
    $affiliates = $affiliates->whereNotIn('id', $invalidIds)->get();
```